# jQuery uploadify error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'queueData' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, upload, uploadify

> Used previously without a broble. But now:

[image]

> All relationships are in accordance with the documentation

```
$("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'method'   : 'post',
            'buttonClass' : 'upload-photo-file',
            'formData' : { 'cmd' : 'download', 'path' : pathPhoto, 'user' : user},
            'auto'     : false,
            'buttonText' : 'Выбрать фото',
            'progressData' : 'speed',
            'swf'      : '/uploadify.swf',
            'uploader' : '/uploadify.php',
            // Some options
            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                $('.results').html(data);
            },
            'itemTemplate' : '<div id="${fileID}" class="uploadify-queue-item">\
                <div class="cancel">\
                    <a class="del-moder-photo" href="javascript:$(\'#${instanceID}\').uploadify(\'cancel\', \'${fileID}\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>\
                </div>\
                <span class="fileName" >${fileName} (${fileSize})</span>\
                <span class="data"></span>\
                <div class="uploadify-progress"><div class="uploadify-progress-bar"><!--Progress Bar--></div></div>\
            </div>'
        });
```

> What happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if you have flashed installed, if you do, make sure that your domain is in the 'allow' section.

If you're using Chrome

1. Go to: chrome://settings/content/flash
2. Add a new entry in the allow section for your domain.

However, this will only work on your node, if it's a solution for some clients, you have to notify them or find some other solution to trigger that you require flash from your website/app somehow.

Hope it works for you.